# Support for Indexing under HIVE ORC format

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hive, ssrs-2012

we are looking to deploy a reporting solution wherein the data is stored in HIVE/Hadoop data layer which would be queried by the reporting layer using SSRS.

Now considering performance optimizations, does it makes sense to think of **indexing** on the  data layer given we would be using **ORC file format** on HIVE.

According to few reference such as below, looks like indexing is inherent to ORC file format? Is that the case or this is something different.

[LanguageManual ORC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC)

I'm new to HIVE/Hadoop, so would appreciate any pointers here. Thanks!

Comment: Your don't need ORC to use INDEX... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/IndexDev#IndexDev-CREATEINDEX

Comment: If you're in a Cloudera environment, Parquet in Impala would much more performant than Hive, though if you have  Hive2 with LLAP, ORC may be fine. Partitioning is also an optimization...

Comment: Thanks for the inputs cricket_007, that's fine what you mentioned that "
Your don't need ORC to use INDEX..". However, my question was more around the fact that we are using ORC format and whether using Indexing with ORC format makes sense, since it seems that ORC format itself has some indexing inherent to it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done (can't remember if I have done it personally). It may provide some performance gains, sure.

Answer (score 0):

The indexes in the ORC files have a different purpose. From the documentation

> light-weight indexes stored within the file skip row groups that don't
>   pass predicate filtering seek to a given row

However the indexes in having are designed to optimize the search on specific columns.

> The goal of Hive indexing is to improve the speed of query lookup on
>   certain columns of a table. Without an index, queries with predicates
>   like 'WHERE tab1.col1 = 10' load the entire table or partition and
>   process all the rows. But if an index exists for col1, then only a
>   portion of the file needs to be loaded and processed.

I am not sure if this improve fit with your reporting model, probably will not help a lot of common aggregations

I hope it helps